# get parameter form's type in function

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having a function which will be called from different forms. this
 function has form obj in parameter, I want to check this form obj
 belogs to which form in my app.

```
public void callAsPopup(System.Windows.Forms.Form  frm)
{
    if(frm.GetType()==frmBatch)
    this.CenterToParent();
    this.Show();
}
```

here `frmBatch` is one of the form in my app

Comment: now we know what you want. But do you have also a question?

Comment: with this code I am  error that 'frmBatch is a type bit is used like a variable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us the [is keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) to check the type

```
public void callAsPopup(System.Windows.Forms.Form  frm)
{
    // sanity check to avoid crash on the Show call.
    if(frm == null)
        return;

    if(frm is  frmBatch)
        this.CenterToParent();
    this.Show();
}
```